# Primitives and built-in functions in Racket

Tags: lisp, racket, primitive, built-in

Are primitives and built-in **functions** the same thing in Racket?
If no, what's the difference between them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is **no**!

A primitive function are those which aren't implemented in its own runtime but inherently implemented by the runtime. eg. `cons` is implemented in C and the racket VM comes with the code that implements it. `list*` too, but it didn't really need to be a primitive. Some primitives are so just to speed things up.

Built in functions just means they come with the language. These are all primitives and all the standard library that is implemented in the language itself and is shipped with the implementation. An example is `make-list`. If you rigth click in the IDE and choose "Open defining file" you'll see it's implementation in racket:

```
(define (make-list n x)
  (unless (exact-nonnegative-integer? n)
    (raise-argument-error 'make-list "exact-nonnegative-integer?" n))
  (let loop ([n n] [r '()])
    (if (zero? n) r (loop (sub1 n) (cons x r)))))
```

An example of function that are neither primitive nor built in would be many of the packages in [pkgs.racket-lang.org](https://pkgs.racket-lang.org/).

Comment: Won't `make-list` be JIT-ted to native code? After that, what use is there for distinguishing it from something built-in? I suppose it's useful for internal bootstrapping: likely certain code in Racket can only rely on primitives, until other things are loaded.

Comment: @Kaz  Built ins that are not primitives don't get better compiled than any other racket code. `make-list` **is** built in, but not primitive, so it gets compiled to bytecode run by the racket VM. Only primitives have native implementations.